# sencha touch :: adding a background-image to a Panel

Tags: coding-style, background-image, sencha-touch

I try to add an image to the background of a panel. the image comes from loaded data.
i tried the following code, which did not work:

```
var topPanel = new Ext.Panel({
        flex:1,
        title:'topPanel',
        style:'style="background-image: url('+this.jsonData.picURL+');'

});
```

when I create a list it work great with 'itemTpl'.

I also tried

```
style:'background-image: url({picURL});'
```

together with

```
store: {
            fields: ['firstName','lastName', 'picURL'],
            data: this.jsondData
        }
```

but then I get the message

> [[object Object]] is not a valid
>   argument for
>   'Function.prototype.apply'.

any thoughts could help!
thnx

Comment: i am now living with a workaround, putting the image in the "html"-property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can append custom style by assigning object to style property of your panel

```
style: {
            backgroundImage: 'url(resources/branding/mobile.gif)',
            backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
            backgroundPosition: 'center'
}
```

Answer (score 3):

and if you want to cover the whole background use:

backgroundSize: 'cover'